# Files created by Azure Function App not visible in Kudu or Console

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

My Azure Function app programmatically creates files in folders such C:\local\LocalAppData or C:\local\Temp

But when I browse by using Kudu or even just the Console, I cannot see the files. This is unlike when it creates inside "C:\home\site\wwwroot", I can see the files immediately.

My app does not throw any I/O exceptions so I am sure it working fine.

Any idea? Will I get the same behavior I use "C:\home\data" instaed?

Comment: How did you deploy your Function App? If you don't see anything via Kudu, it might not have been deployed correctly.

Comment: Via Visual Studio > Publish and Zip Deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\local` is a [temporary storage](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files)   where you can store up to 500mb. After 12 hours, these files get automatically deleted. You can access those files directly from your function.

[image]

> Will I get the same behavior I use "C:\home\data" instaed?

Unlike temporary files the data in `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\home` persists as long as the Function host process is running.